# Method to determine the required sample size: distance or number?

Tags: sampling, sample-size

I'm working on a problem that requires me to carry out a survey of the condition of 5000 footpaths which cover total distance of 2573 km. The condition outcomes are either 'Pass' or 'Fail'. I only want to survey a proportion of the network to provide an estimate of the overall condition but the lengths of all of these footpaths varies quite considerably (from a few metres to kilometres). The research question I would like to answer through this survey is: What proportion of the total length of paths meet the ease of use criteria (i.e. pass)?

My question is, what sample size do I need to provide this estimate for the overall network? Should I base this on distance or on the number of paths?

I've been using a method on the following site but I'm not sure if its correct: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat506/node/11/

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you plan to characterize, describe, or quantify the 'overall condition'?  For instance, if it is in terms of proportion of individual footpaths that would suggest letting the footpath be the basic sampling unit, whereas if it is in terms of total length, that would suggest a different sampling method.  In the latter case, a model of correlation along the path--whether implicit or explicit--would be an important feature of the sample size determination.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and help. The research question is: What proportion of the total length of paths meet the ease of use criteria (i.e. pass)? So it would be the latter case.

Comment: Thank you.  Please include that information in your post so that all readers will be aware of it.  And welcome to CV!